# how to find path of python file in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery

```
$.ajax({ url: "test.py"
```

For example in above code for Python file which path I have to use.

I am testing locally in google app engine.

Answer (score 2):

In an AJAX call, you don't want to provide a path to the location of the .py file on your machine (or on the server), but rather the URL to call.  Unless you've set up a handler for test.py in app.yaml, you're probably not going to be calling a URL containing "test.py" in App Engine.  You want to provide a URL (either relative or absolute) that's mapped to the test.py script in your app.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

When you define an URL in your YAML configuration file, you specify that this URL have to call an script. What you have to do, is form an string that calls an specific action into this script. This is not something file based, like in PHP or other popular scripting languages.

So, it depends on how you've formed your routes.

This mapping occurs when you define the `WSGIApplication`, in your main script. But if you're using an specific framework, you'll have to look how to generate an URL from a controller/action tuple, or whatever this framework uses.